# what is the intension of the following code in a jade template

Tags: javascript, pug

while exploring a jade template i encountered the following inline snippet

```
script
  <!--
  !{state.toString().replace(/<\//g,"<\\/").replace(/-->/g, "--\\>")}
  -->
```

removing the following lines. gets the page to loose the gloobal variables.
I would like to know what is the `<!--` synatx, and what is the equivalent expression for plain html with inline script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string inside `#{myvar} // buffered` or `!{mayvar} //unbufferd` is a way to render strings after or while building the HTML document.

In your case the author possibly tried to display or render some html or regular javascript code, but usually the following lines behind `script.` are used to render regular HTML / Javascript. Thats the reason why he used html comment syntax before and after the line.

For example:

```
script.
  var myvar = function() {
    // Do some stuff
  };
  return myvar();
```

will be rendered to:

```
<script>
  var myvar = function() {
    // Do some stuff
  };
  return myvar();      
</script>
```

while:

```
script
  !{myvar} // unbuffered
```

or

```
script
  #{myvar} // buffered
```

should throw an error like `unexepted new line` or will be rendered to:

```
<script>
  #{myvar} // buffered
</script>
```

Comment: should the equivalent code for plain html be {{{myVar}}}